# Android Creating Bitmap Size on Screen Density

Tags: android, bitmap

In my app I need to make bitmap icons that get overlaid on a Google Map View like so.

```
public Bitmap makeBubble(int radius, int color) {
    Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(radius * 2, radius * 2, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bm);

    Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    paint.setColor(color);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    canvas.drawCircle(bm.getWidth() / 2, bm.getHeight() / 2, radius, paint);

    paint.setColor(Color.argb(255, Color.red(color), Color.green(color), Color.blue(color)));
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    canvas.drawCircle(bm.getWidth() / 2, bm.getHeight() / 2, radius, paint);
    return bm;
}
```

However, these icons have significantly different sizes on different screen densities (as would be expected).

How do I create them in the same size on all screen densities?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do it is defining a dimension in XML: (you can rename it)

```
<!-- file: /res/values/dimentions.xml (you can rename the file) -->
<resources>
    <dimen name="circle_radius">24dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

And then wherever you call this function `makeBubble` do this:

```
int radius  = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.circle_radius);
makeBubble(radius, color)
```

You can get a context or resources from Activity, Fragment or View so you probably can get one of these. Don't use the application context as that will give you some problems in edge conditions.

**Update:**

After your comment, you seem to need to calculate the value programmatically. Just multiply your radius by `DisplayMetrics.density`

Here's how to do it:

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
int radius = ...; // original calculation
radius *= metrics.density; // now this is adjusted for screen density
```

[Here's the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html#density)

Comment: I calculate the radius before calling this function (radius can be any value, not defined beforehand), so I can't use a set value in resources.

Comment: how do you calculate the radius? based on what?

Comment: The radius is calculated based upon another factor, but my real question is how to make sure that given the same radius on two devices, the bitmap drawn will be the same physical size regardless of screen density.